# Change overflow popup menu item text color

Tags: android, menuitem

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0UaS.png]

I cannot change the text color of the overflow menu item.
It uses the textColorPrimary of my Theme

I added this code to my theme in styles.xml

```
 <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

but still it appears to be white.

Answer (score 0):

In styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/MyPopupTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyPopupTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ff0004</item>
</style>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: still white. why is it its using my theme's textColorPrimary?

Comment: Create an empty project and perform only mentioned changes. Tested.

Comment: Yes its working but not on my project. What could be the cause?

Comment: What theme does your activity have? If it is `NoActionBar`, that apply `app:popupTheme`  with this style to your  `Toolbar`.

Comment: Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar